# Coping swf resources with flex-mojos to the custom folder

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flexmojos, flex-mojos

How I can configure `copy-flex-resources` goal and `swf` dependencies to copy swf files to the custom folder in my web-app? By default it copies to the web-app root.

More about `copy-flex-resources` goal here:
https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Copy+Flex+Resources

Answer (score 0):

Your can add a "configuration" to that plugin:

```
<configuration> 
    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappDirectory> 
    <!-- If RSLs are coming from the WAR uncomment this line 
    <copyRSL>false</copyRSL>--> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Benoit, thank you for your reply. What about the case when I have several swfs from several sub-projects that I have to copy into different folders in my web-app? Can I do it too somehow?

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe you can ask for a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

I use maven-antrun-plugin to copy several swfs from several sub projects
(there's probably a better way, but it does the job)

> ```
> <plugin>
>     <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>             
>             <phase>process-resources</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>run</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>                 <tasks>
>                     <move file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/mySwf-${project.version}.swf"
>                         tofile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/somedir/mySwf.swf" />
>                 </tasks>
>             </configuration>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
>   </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For the war project the maven-dependency-plugin is the somewhat better choice.  It can copy different resources to different places and keeps in sync with your versions declared in your dependencies.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>copy-content</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>barstyles</artifactId>
                                    <type>swf</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${flashAppDir}/bar</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>barstyles.swf</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.graniteds</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>graniteds</artifactId>
                                    <type>swf</type>
                                 <outputDirectory>${flashAppDir}/thirdparty</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>graniteds.swf</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                               </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```